# Scraping a table from the web omits certain values

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on a little coding project to help learn how webscraping works, and decided to extract a table from a fantasy football website I like, which can be found here. https://fantasydata.com/nfl/fantasy-football-leaders?position=1&team=1&season=2018&seasontype=1&scope=1&subscope=1&scoringsystem=2&aggregatescope=1&range=1

When I attempt to grab the table the first 10 rows come out okay, but starting Brian Hill's row every value in my table comes up blank.  I have inspected the web page as I usually do whenever I run into an issue, and the rows following Hill's seem to follow an identical structure to the ones before it. Any helping both resolving the issue and potentially explaining why it is happening in the first place would be much appreciated!

```
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   
from selenium import webdriver


URLA = 'https://fantasydata.com/nfl/fantasy-football-leaders?position='
URLB = '&team='
URLC = '&season='
URLD = '&seasontype=1&scope=1&subscope=1&scoringsystem=2&aggregatescope=1&range=3'
POSITIONNUMBER = [1,6,7]


TEAMNUMBER = [1]


def buildStatsTable(year):
    fullDF = pandas.DataFrame()
    fullLength = 0
    position = 1
    headers = ['Name', 'Team', 'Pos', 'GMS', 'PassingYards', 'PassingTDs', 'PassingINTs',
               'RushingYDs', 'RushingTDs', 'ReceivingRECs', 'ReceivingYDs', 'ReceivingTDs', 
               'FUM LST', 'PPG', 'FPTS']
    for team in TEAMNUMBER:
        currURL = URLA + str(position)+ URLB + str(team)+URLC+str(year)+URLD
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(currURL)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
        driver.quit()
        tr = soup.findAll('tr', {'role' : 'row'})
        length = len(tr)
        offset = length/2
        maxCap = int((length - 1)/2) + 1
        tableList = []
        for i, row in enumerate(tr[2:maxCap]):
            player = row.get_text().split('\n', 2)[1]
            player_row = [value.get_text() for value in tr[int(i + offset + 1)].contents]
            tableList.append([player] + player_row)
        teamDF = pandas.DataFrame(columns = headers, data = tableList)
        fullLength = fullLength + len(tableList)
        fullDF = fullDF.append(teamDF)
    fullDF.index = list(range(0,fullLength))
    return fullDF

falcons = buildStatsTable(2018)
```

Actual Results (only showed the fist few columns to make the post shorter, the issue is consistent across every column)

```
 Name Team Pos GMS PassingYards PassingTDs PassingINTs  \
0         Matt Ryan  ATL  QB  16         4924         35           7   
1       Julio Jones  ATL  WR  16            0          0           0   
2     Calvin Ridley  ATL  WR  16            0          0           0   
3     Tevin Coleman  ATL  RB  16            0          0           0   
4      Mohamed Sanu  ATL  WR  16            5          1           0   
5     Austin Hooper  ATL  TE  16            0          0           0   
6         Ito Smith  ATL  RB  14            0          0           0   
7      Justin Hardy  ATL  WR  16            0          0           0   
8       Marvin Hall  ATL  WR  16            0          0           0   
9     Logan Paulsen  ATL  TE  15            0          0           0   
10       Brian Hill  ATL  RB                                           
11  Devonta Freeman  ATL  RB                                           
12     Russell Gage  ATL  WR                                           
13     Eric Saubert  ATL  TE
```

Comment: Because when you don't login the table is actually blank from row 10

Comment: so to clarify, since I am signed in when I visit the website normally I can see the table, but when I attempt to scrape the table from it I can only see what non-members have access to? And if that is the case, do you know of a way to somehow pass my login credentials as query parameters such that I can scrape the other rows?

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this](http://kazuar.github.io/scraping-tutorial/)

Comment: @Bill, no, it won't work that way. The web site will probably be relying on serverside sessions, cookies, tokens etc to verify that you're logged in, which won't work with a simply query param.

Comment: @Dino ironically I had just found that webpage, thank you though! very helpful

Comment: If there is a login page simply use send_keys to pass login details via selenium